# How to have several CRUD methods using a proxy with Sencha Touch 2 framework?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, crud, sencha-touch-2.1

I've coded a small mobile application using Sencha Touch 2 framework. For the moment, I manage some articles from a database in localhost. I've written a database management using PHP CRUD methods contained here in ArticleService.php file. My 'read' fonction get back all the articles. But I want to have an other 'read' method to read for exemple a specific article according to its id or the last 5 articles, etc. But the store proxy (I think so) allows 1 methods for each main operation. So in my case, for 'read' operation I just have an only 'read' method.

Here's is my 'store' source code :

```
Ext.define("MyApp.store.ArticleStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: ["MyApp.model.ArticleModel"],
    config: {
    model: "MyApp.model.ArticleModel",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        api: {
            create: "http://localhost/MobileApplication/MyApp/services/ArticleService.php?action=create",
            read: "http://localhost/MobileApplication/MyApp/services/ArticleService.php?action=read",
            update: "http://localhost/MobileApplication/MyApp/services/ArticleService.php?action=update",
            destroy: "http://localhost/MobileApplication/MyApp/services/ArticleService.php?action=destroy"
        },
         extraParams: {
            keyword: ""
        },
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "articles",
            totalProperty: "total"
        }
    },
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

Is there a possible way to have several methods for each main CRUD operation (for example 3 differents 'read' methods to manage my articles display) ? I'm really lost.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Isn't it besser to send different params to the server?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need different methods for read. Once you load the store it will be in the memory and you will be able to find any record you want.

If you're store is too big to be loaded at once - take a look at `remoteFilter` property: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-remoteFilter This way filters you will set up (like id = 1 or parent_id = 2) will be passed to the server so it can return proper record set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works nice now. But if I want to make two differents request so two differents filters I think it's not possible because of cache. So the solution should be to have two differents instance of my ArticleStore. how can I do this ? I didn't find any tutorial talking about this. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: You can clone one store after loading it and have two copies locally. And then filter it - assuming your store is small and you're loading it at the same time.

Comment: Ok. But how can I differentiate the two different instances in my view ? With its Id ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I suggest you post another question explaining in detail what exactly you're trying to achieve. This way we can help you not in comments.

Comment: I've already posted an other question but no one have responded since many time that why I came back to you. here's the url of my new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914543/how-can-i-handle-several-store-instance-in-the-same-action-using-sencha-touch-2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeap. I see that. I will answer it there