# How can I handle several store instance in the same action using Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I coded a simple application which displays a dataview.List articles in the home page.

Here's a view of my home page :

[image]

I can also open a specific article by clicking on it and have its complete description in an other view.

Here's my article view page for a specific article :

[image]

To do this I apply a filter in my ArticleController class (here I get the matched record).

```
onViewArticle: function(record) {
        var articleStore = Ext.getStore("ArticleStore");
        var selectedArticle = record;
        articleStore.filterBy(function(record, id) {
            if (selectedArticle.data.id == id)
                return (true);
            return (false);
        });
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.getArticleViewConnexContainer(), {
            type: "slide", direction: "left"
        });
    },
```

And here's my store class :

```
Ext.define("MyApp.store.ArticleStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: ["MyApp.model.ArticleModel"],
    config: {
    model: "MyApp.model.ArticleModel",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        api: {
            create: "http://localhost/MobileApplication/MyApp/services/ArticleService.php?action=create",
            read: "http://localhost/MobileApplication/MyApp/services/ArticleService.php?action=read",
            update: "http://localhost/MobileApplication/MyApp/services/ArticleService.php?action=update",
            destroy: "http://localhost/MobileApplication/MyApp/services/ArticleService.php?action=destroy"
        },
         extraParams: {
            keyword: ""
        },
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "articles",
            totalProperty: "total"
        }
    },
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

But now, I want to apply another filter in the same action to list others articles (with another specific filter) just below the article description. This involve to use two differents filters I think (one to get back the specific article (already done here) and an other one for the article list I want just below the article description). But how can I do this ? If I apply two filters in the same controller function, the second one will destroy the prevent one because all store data are in the cache. Is there a possible way (like in php MVC frameworks for instance) to send a variable from the controller to the view and display its content (By this way I will have two differents variables and I will can display the content of my two requests on my view)? Or maybe a possible way to handle several stores in the same time ? I'm really lost. Does anyone can help me, please ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you tell me, why exactly you are applying a filter on the store? I didn't get the last para of your question.

Comment: I apply a filter in my controller, not on my store. The 'onViewArticle' method comes from my controller and its goal is to filter my records and register the selected one. I have updated my question by adding the store class definition. I use a proxy to do my sql resquests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually couple questions inside.

Sencha Framework is built with "one store - one view" concept in mind. So if you have two different view presenting information from really one data store, you still would need to have two copies of this store. You can clear/apply back filters if you don't need to show these two views at the same time (it's mostly true in case of phone applications), but I would recommend to have two separate copies.

As far as your scenario - I don't think you need that. When you're displaying particular book you don't need to filter store. You need to just load one record (`store.getAt()`) and then use this record in your child form.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again for your help. It was very helpfull. I'll follow your advices. Have a good day. Bye.